# Python - Schedule to close a program

Tags: python-3.x, taskkill

I run a program that needs to be closed by 10pm. I leave office at 9:30 PM. It would be wonderful if I had a script that closes this program automatically after 30 minutes. That would allow me to leave early and not have to wait to close it out maunally.

If I run the script below, it closes program instantly :(

```
import os
import time

# This program will attempt to close skype every 1 minute
while 1 :
    os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM skype.exe")
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: How are you running this? If it's closing, that would suggest that you're getting an error. Try running this in a different context and see if you get an error

Comment: You execute `TASKKILL /F /IM skype.exe` instantly. Why are you surprised?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import time

# This program will attempt to close skype every 1 minute
while 1 :
    os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM skype.exe")
    time.sleep(60)
```

to

```
import os
import time

# This program will attempt to close skype every 1 minute
while 1 :
time.sleep(60)
os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM skype.exe")
```

os.system was before the time.sleep, that means its closing the system and waiting 60 sec